# trying to get only 1 result out of an sql query which returns a whole list including duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
```

This results in the following:

```
  ID  |  Description  |  Foreign_ID

  1   |  5060:Stat    |  4321

  2   |  5060:Stat    |  4321

  3   |  7060:Pleb    |  5423

  4   |  5060:Stat    |  4321

  5   |  7070:Pleb    |  5423

  6   |  6509:Stat    |  4321
```

How can i return the following where i only get 1 record from the records with the same foreign_ID? Like:

```
 1   |  5060:Stat    |  4321

 3   |  7060:Pleb    |  5423
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (foreign_id) t.*
from t
order by foreign_id;
```

This will return an arbitrary row.  If you want the one with the minimum `id`:

```
order by foreign_id, id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GROUP BY to group the query by Foreign id:

```
SELECT * FROM <Table> GROUP BY Foreign_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `distinct on` clause

```
select distinct on (Foreign_ID)
ID, Description, Foreign_ID
from <table>
```

You may also want to use the `order by` clause

```
select distinct on (Foreign_ID)
ID, Description, Foreign_ID
from <table>
order by ID
```